# Why is djangorest returning blank brackets on simple get request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to return a list view of a database records. In testing my database has three records. When my view function is called it returns 3 empty curly brackets instead of the items it should. What is wrong here? The serializer, url and included below. I am not running any special settings.

````
#view
@api_view(['GET'])
def getTheWashers(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        washer = DishDoer.objects.all()
    
    washer_serializer = DishDoerSerializer(washer, many=True)
    return Response(washer_serializer.data)```


#seriaizer
class DishDoerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DishDoer 
        fields = "__all__"

#url
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')), 
    path('api/washers', getTheWashers), 
]
````

Comment: Please attach the DishDoer model code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with your serializer. Instead of inheriting from **serializers.Serializer**, you should inherit from **serializers.ModelSerializer** since you want to use all the fields from your DishDoer model.

```
class DishDoerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DishDoer 
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank You